# Метод filter для матриц

Tags: javascript

Необходимо написать функцию, которая возвращает элементы, находящиеся под главной диагональю матрицы с использованием метода `filter`. Функция написана, но работает неправильно. Она возвращает только элементы с одной строки, а не со всей матрицы. Как исправить?

```js
 var numbers = [
      [1,2,3],
      [4,5,6],
      [7,8,9]
    ];
    
function filteredArray(){
  var filtered;
  for(var outerIndex in numbers) {
     filtered = numbers[outerIndex].filter((element, innerIndex) => {
      if (outerIndex > innerIndex) 
        return element;
    });
  }
  console.log(filtered);
  return filtered;
}

var result = filteredArray();
console.log(result); //7.8 вместо 4,7,8
```

Comment: дак вы проходя каждую строку заменяете `filtered`, а надо добавлять туда

Answer (score 1):

```
function filteredArray(){
  var filtered = [];
  for(var outerIndex in numbers) {
     numbers[outerIndex].filter((element, innerIndex) => {
      if (outerIndex > innerIndex)
        filtered.push(element);
    });
  }
  return filtered;
}

var result = filteredArray();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы так странно используете filter, то почему бы не так

```js
 var numbers = [
      [1,2,3],
      [4,5,6],
      [7,8,9]
    ];
    
filtered = []    
numbers.filter((e,i)=> filtered.push(...e.slice(0,i)))
console.log(filtered)
```

А если его использовать. как он задуман, то уж как-то так, пусть он что-то фильтрует

```js
 var numbers = [
      [1,2,3],
      [4,5,6],
      [7,8,9]
    ];
    
function filteredArray(){
  var filtered = [];
  for(var outerIndex in numbers) {
     filtered.push(...numbers[outerIndex]
             .filter((element, innerIndex) => outerIndex > innerIndex));
  }
  return filtered;
}

var result = filteredArray();
console.log(result);
```